# timer won't run in background in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

I have made a timer in react JS but my only problem is when I switch tabs the timer doesn't run in the background. How do I fix this?

Here is the code ->

```
const [time, setTime] = useState({ms:0, s:0, m:0, h:0});
    const [interv, setInterv] = useState();
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(0);
    // Not started = 0
    // started = 1
    // stopped = 2
  
    const start = () => {
      run();
      setStatus(1);
      setInterv(setInterval(run, 10));
    };
  
    var updatedMs = time.ms, updatedS = time.s, updatedM = time.m, updatedH = time.h;
  
    const run = () => {
      if(updatedM === 60){
        updatedH++;
        updatedM = 0;
      }
      if(updatedS === 60){
        updatedM++;
        updatedS = 0;
      }
      if(updatedMs === 100){
        updatedS++;
        updatedMs = 0;
      }
      updatedMs++;
      return setTime({ms:updatedMs, s:updatedS, m:updatedM, h:updatedH});
    };
  
    const stop = () => {
      clearInterval(interv);
      setStatus(2);
    };
```

Comment: Could you please share your code so we can help further?

Comment: hey sorry about that just did!